# Netty ByteBuf First Time Implementation

Tags: java, netty

My Plan is to have a message protocol as outlined below:

- `MessageLength`: integer with total message length
- `MessageID`: integer with auto incrementing identifier
- `MessageType`: integer (`enum`) with the type of message
- `Payload`: `byte[]` with the Payload of the message (Serialised POJO)

At the moment I just am looking at making sure I create the `ByteBuf` in the correct and optimal way.  At this stage I have the following:

```
io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf buf = Unpooled.buffer();

// Test Data Class
TestData test = new TestData("FirstName", "LastName", 40);

// Convert to Bytes is method to return the Byte Array (Serialised POJO)
byte[] payload = convertToBytes(test);

// Write 1 simulating MessageID 1
buf.writeInt(1);

// Write 2 simulating MessageType of 2
buf.writeInt(2);

// Write The Payload data<BR>
buf.writeBytes(payload);
```

The goal would be to them pass on to a `LengthFieldPrepender` and up the pipeline.

Is this the right way to create the `ByteBuf`?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the allocator to create the ByteBuf if possible as this may give you a pooled ByteBuf (depending on the configuration).

Something like:

```
Channel channel = ...
channel.alloc().buffer(expectedSize)
```

Also note that I passed in the expected size of the ByteBuf as this will ensure we not need to expand it later on when you fill it.